Time dependency of Wave function and its probability density function (PDF)
When we study the Schrodinger wave equation, we have a time dependent wave function $\Psi(x,t)$, and when we deduce its Probability Density function we come to know there is no time dependence in the PDF.
So, can we conclude that if the wave function is time dependent it may or may not be necessary that its PDF will also be time dependent.

when we deduce its Probability Density function we come to know there is no time dependence in the PDF. This is not generally true. In what context did you find this?


When we study the Schrodinger wave equation,
we have a time dependent wave function $\Psi(x,t)$,
and when we deduce its Probability Density function
we come to know there is no time dependence in the PDF.

This is only true for stationary states
(i.e. eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator,
with a well-defined energy $E$).
Then the wave function is
$$\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
and the probability density function
$$\rho(x,t)=|\Psi(x,t)|^2=|\psi(x)|^2$$
indeed does not depend on time $t$.
But when solving Schrödinger's time-dependent equation
the most general solutions are wave functions like
$$\Psi(x,t)=\sum_nc_n\psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}.$$
And if more than one of the constants $c_n$ are non-zero,
then the probability density function does depend on time $t$.
